# LiveData of a list notifies observers without calling setValue or postValue

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have a `MutableLiveData` like this in my view model:

```
val liveData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<*>>()‍‍‍‍‍
```

I add the results from an endpoint call to this `LiveData` like this:

```
liveData.value?.addAll(myList)
```

as far as I know, `MutableLiveData` shouldn't notify it's `Observer`s unless you do a `setValue` or `postValue` on it but at this point when my code is run, `Observer`s are notified of the change.

How is this possible?

---

#### Update:

I came across an even more stranger behavior, this test passes but the list gets printed one time: `[]`

```
    @Test
    fun `strange live data behavior`() {
        val myLiveData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Int>>()
        val observer = mock() as Observer<ArrayList<Int>>
        myLiveData.observeForever(observer)
        myLiveData.observeForever { println(it) }
        myLiveData.value = ArrayList()
        verify(observer).onChanged(ArrayList())
        myLiveData.value?.addAll(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4))
        val result = ArrayList<Int>()
        result.add(1)
        result.add(2)
        result.add(3)
        result.add(4)
        verify(observer).onChanged(result)
    }
```

Comment: There is one more case when `Observer` is notified. When `Observer` attaches to a `LiveData` and that `LiveData` already contains a value, then that `Observer` will receive a notification immediately.

Comment: Yes, but this happens even after that

Comment: @SanlokLee I've updated the question with more information

Comment: I see what you mean now. I will attach an answer shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a `LiveData` sends a notification, `LiveData` does not send a copy of the item. Instead, it simply pass a reference to the same instance that is holding.

This means that if you modified the data inside the `LiveData` like this:

`myLiveData.value?.addAll(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4))`

The `ArrayList` object that the observer previously received will also be modified **without `Observer.onChanged()` getting called**, simply because they are the same object. This is why using a mutable object in `LiveData` or any Observer/reactive Pattern is generally not a good idea.

To verify that `onChanged()` is actually called only once, add this line at the end of the test:

```
    @Test
    fun `strange live data behavior`() {
        val myLiveData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Int>>()
        val observer = mock() as Observer<ArrayList<Int>>
        myLiveData.observeForever(observer)
        myLiveData.observeForever { println(it) }
        myLiveData.value = ArrayList()
        verify(observer).onChanged(ArrayList())
        myLiveData.value?.addAll(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4))
        val result = ArrayList<Int>()
        result.add(1)
        result.add(2)
        result.add(3)
        result.add(4)
        verify(observer).onChanged(result)

        // Below should pass because onChanged is only called once.
        verify(observer, times(1)).onChanged(any()) 
    }
```